# Using HTML and CSS to abbreviate a title as its container is resized

Tags: html, css

I am building an event calendar for a web site, and I would like to present it such that *if the viewport is resized to be smaller, the day titles become standard abbreviations.* That is, ‘Sunday’ would become ‘Sun’, then just ‘S’ if the viewport were reduced further.

One way I have thought to approach it is to define the names and abbreviations as classes, as follows.

```
<div class="day">
    <div class="full">Sunday</div>
    <div class="abbr">Sun</div>
    <div class="init">S</div>
</div>
```

Then those elements could have fixed widths, like this.

```
.day .full
{
    width: 100px;
}

.day .abbr
{
    width: 50px;
}
```

However, I do not know whether this approach can work, as I can not think of how the elements might be wrapped out of view in the container, *nor how they might remain centred in the container*.

Has anyone worked with an effect like this without employing Javascript? It strikes me that the mechanics of CSS should probably be able to do it, but I can not see how.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add another possibility see below. However the one cela proposed is more screen reader friendly (if you incorporate the `<abbr>` element in the abbreviated versions). Or a more popular (and generally better option) is to just use the `text-overflow: ellipsis` property and let it be fluid. Or another [popular ux option](https://codepen.io/chris-w/pen/ajQOdK) instead.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  div:before {
    content: "S"
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  div:before {
    content: "Sun"
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  div:before {
    content: "Sunday"
  }
}

div { font-size: 5rem }
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS `@media` rules to achieve this. In the below case, if the viewport width is at 600px, it will the apply the styles inside the rule. In your case, it will hide the full word and display the abbreviation.

Here is the link to documentation on it: [CSS @media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)

```css
.abbr {
  display: none;
}
.init {
  display: none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
  .full {
    display: none;
  }
  .abbr {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="day">
    <div class="full">Sunday</div>
    <div class="abbr">Sun</div>
    <div class="init">S</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not edit HTML via CSS (unfortunately), but you can add content via `pseudo-elements` and then edit them via a CSS `@media query`.

I added 7 `spans` each representing one day of the week and passing the class `.day` to them to identify them in my CSS. I then used the `nth-type-of()` selector and added the correct titles via the `content:'';` property in the `::after` pseudo-element, using a `@media query` you can now edit these titles as often and to whatever you want.

```css
span.day:nth-of-type(1)::after {
  content: "Monday";
}

span.day:nth-of-type(2)::after {
  content: "Tuesday";
}

span.day:nth-of-type(3)::after {
  content: "Wednesday";
}

span.day:nth-of-type(4)::after {
  content: "Thirstday";
}

span.day:nth-of-type(5)::after {
  content: "Friday";
}

span.day:nth-of-type(6)::after {
  content: "Satturday";
}

span.day:nth-of-type(7)::after {
  content: "Sunday";
}


@media (max-width: 740px) {
  span.day:nth-of-type(1)::after {
    content: "Mo";
  }

  span.day:nth-of-type(2)::after {
    content: "Tu";
  }

  span.day:nth-of-type(3)::after {
    content: "We";
  }

  span.day:nth-of-type(4)::after {
    content: "Th";
  }

  span.day:nth-of-type(5)::after {
    content: "Fr";
  }

  span.day:nth-of-type(6)::after {
    content: "Sa";
  }

  span.day:nth-of-type(7)::after {
    content: "Su";
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- each representing one day of the week -->

<span class="day"></span>
<span class="day"></span>
<span class="day"></span>
<span class="day"></span>
<span class="day"></span>
<span class="day"></span>
<span class="day"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way in which this problem can be solved without `@media` rules is to divide the day names into their components, then make the container `display: flex`, and apply `flex-wrap: wrap` with `overflow: hidden`.

(In the following example, the font kerning between the capital and the rest of the word is unnatural because they are separated into *divs*, but that could be circumnavigated easily with additional styling.)

```css
.day {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 200px;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #999f;
}

.day>div {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1em;
  font-size: 60px;
  background-color: #dddf;
}
```

```html
<div class="day">
  <div>W</div>
  <div>ed</div>
  <div>nesday</div>
</div>
```